# EXD_BAD_ACCESS passing data back to delegate

Tags: iphone, xcode, delegates

I'm a relatively new iPhone developer and am making great progress building my 2nd iPhone app. In the app I'm building now I'm doing some code separation with some protocols and delegates so that I car re-use some of my code in a variety of places throughout my code.

Here's what I want to happen:

1. CITRootViewController creates an instance of a CITReportCreator class, passing itself as a property so that the reportCreator can open additional view controllers and such.
2. CITReportCreator class is declared as implementing the CITImageCaptureDelegate protocol, which is declared in the CITImageCaptureViewController file.
3. CITImageCaptureViewController defines the delegate protocol and has a method that passes back data and references to the child view controller so that CITReportCreator can interact with it's data, close the related XIB, etc.

I believe I'm getting the delegate and protocol established correctly, and verified that my 'delegate' object still contains data when it is called, but I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS method when my view controller tries to pass data back to the delegate in this line of code:

```
   [self.delegate childViewControllerDidFinish:self];
```

Here's a good portion of the rest of my code. I had this working by using CITRootViewController as my delegate instead of the CITReportCreator class, but now that I'm separating the code, something has broke.

CITReootViewController.m (the view controller that calls the Report Creator)

```
//create a nrew report
-(IBAction)createReport:(id)sender {
    CITReportCreator *report = [CITReportCreator alloc];
    [report createNewReport:self];
}
```

CITReportCreator.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CITImageCaptureViewController.h"

@interface CITReportCreator : NSObject <CITImageCaptureDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imageList;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger imageIndex;


-(int) createNewReport:(UIViewController *)parent ;

//Delegate Methods
-(void) childViewControllerDidFinish:(UIViewController*)viewController;
@end
```

And CITReportCreator.m

```
#import "CITReportCreator.h"

@implementation CITReportCreator
{
    UIViewController *parentController;
}

@synthesize  imageList;
@synthesize imageIndex;

-(int) createNewReport:(UIViewController *)parent
{

//store a reference to the parent view controller
parentController = parent;

// init code....

//head to the first image capture view
[self  startImageCapture];
return 0;
}  

-(int)startImageCapture
{
//pull the image name from the array of images
NSString *imageName = [imageList objectAtIndex:imageIndex];

//prep the image capture controller
CITImageCaptureViewController *capture = [[CITImageCaptureViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CITImageCaptureViewController" bundle:nil];

//Assign the capture controller's delegate
capture.imageName = imageName;
capture.delegate = self;

//Display the capture controller
[parentController presentModalViewController:capture animated:YES];

return 0;
}


//a break point set here never gets hit.
-(void) childViewControllerDidFinish:(UIViewController*)viewController;
{
[viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}

@end
```

And finally, the CITImageCaptureViewControllers

CITImageCaptureViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol CITImageCaptureDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) childViewControllerDidFinish:(UIViewController*)viewController;
@end


@interface CITImageCaptureViewController : UIViewController 
{
id<CITImageCaptureDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) id<CITImageCaptureDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *imageName;

//continue button pressed method
-(IBAction)continueButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

And the .m file

```
#import "CITImageCaptureViewController.h"

@interface CITImageCaptureViewController ()
@end

@implementation CITImageCaptureViewController
@synthesize navItem;

@synthesize  imageName;
@synthesize  delegate = _delegate; //i think this may be part of the problem

//cutting out initWithNibName, viewDidLoad, etc...



- (IBAction)continueButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
[self.delegate childViewControllerDidFinish:self];
} 
@end
```

I find nothing with delegates and protocols all that simple, but I'm guessing I'm missing a small change somewhere. Can you help me head in the right direction?

Comment: That's way too much code to ask someone to review.  But odds are this is a "data go POOF!" situation where some data item was not properly retained.  Learn to read the exception traceback and the simulator stack display (or at least include those items here) to make some progress debugging this.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I think what may be happening is my report object created at the very beginning is falling out of scope and there's no reference to it left when the calling procedure comes back.

My apologies on the amount of code.

Comment: I think you're right.  Your best bet is to change `CITReportCreator *report = [CITReportCreator alloc];` so that it assigns to a strong property instead of a local variable.  (Note: this is a case where turning on zombies would probably be the quickest way to verify what has gone wrong.)